# Disable spiral in word cloud and display all the words in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, word-cloud

Highcharts introduced word cloud in version 6.

I was trying out and I faced few problems which were not documented

- How to disable the spiral nature and layout it horizontally?
- All the words are not being displayed. In the below screenshot, there are exactly 500 words. But I cannot see them.
- Lot's of empty space on either side.

I have exactly 500 words in this word cloud. With minimum weight as 5 and adding one to each additional word. So weights ranges from 5 to 505.

I have tried doing this, but no use.

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.wordcloud.prototype.deriveFontSize = function(relativeWeight) {
        var maxFontSize = 48;
        // Will return a fontSize between 0px and 25px.
        let size =  Math.floor(maxFontSize * relativeWeight);
        return size < 8 ? 8 : size;
    };
```

I have set the width to 100% but it is still not occupying the whole area

[Updated Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ynr4oszw/3/)

[image]

**UPDATE**
I disabled the spiral nature by writing my own placement strategy like below. Just a copy paste of Highcharts original example and disabling rotation

```
var getRandomPosition = function getRandomPosition(size) {
        return Math.round((size * (Math.random() + 0.5)) / 2);
};

var randomPlacement = function randomPlacement(point, options) {
    var field = options.field,
        r = options.rotation;
    return {
        x: getRandomPosition(field.width) - (field.width / 2),
        y: getRandomPosition(field.height) - (field.height / 2),
        rotation: 0
    };
}

Highcharts.seriesTypes.wordcloud.prototype.placementStrategy.randomHorizontal = randomPlacement;
```

I also set the margins. But it did not help

```
marginRight: 0,
marginLeft: 0
marginBottom: 0
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The latest release from highcharts has fixed my issue. But there are still other issues in the issue tracker opened by me in the highcharts.

Track it here
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7241

Answer (score -1):

Addressing to <del>second and</del> third

<del>Second there are all words in the chart but some are in very small size difficult to see. Here I use `deriveFont`</del>

Third you can use [chart.margin](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.margin) to reduce space outer edge of the chart and the plot area

This demo shows how to deal with <del>second and</del> third

```
/*Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
   data[key].name=key
});// just for demo to show 500 words populating*/
Highcharts.seriesTypes.wordcloud.prototype.deriveFontSize = function(relativeWeight) {
        var maxFontSize =10;
        // Will return a fontSize between 0px and 25px.
        let size =  Math.floor(maxFontSize * relativeWeight);
        return size < 8 ? 15 : size;  //sets min size to be 15 if less than 8
    };
Highcharts.chart('container', {
 chart: {
    "type": "wordcloud",
        margin: [20, 0, 0, 0]
  },
  "series": [{

    "data": data,
   "placementStrategy": 'random'
  }],
  "title": {
    "text": "WORD CLOUD"
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8j8yrbwd/) demo

**Update**

It is not showing all 500 words. It will show all words only when font size is very small.

Comment: chart.margin helps to a certain extent. But try resizing the pane for the chart area to little bit more wider. You will see even though we have kept margin right and margin left to zero, there is still lot of white spaces.

Answer (score -1):

**Workaround** for reducing the spaces on both sides of the plot (in this particular case):

You can use negative margins:

```
marginRight: -300,
marginLeft: -300
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/eyuvcpLe/

Comment: I can't use negative absolute margins... We use percentages and for different screen size margin should be different. So this will not work